# Vb.net: Is it possible to return sql select statement Results as html table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Here is my code

```
 Protected Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
 Dim sSQL As String
 sSQL = "Select (ID),fromcur as 'From Currency',tocur as 'To Currency',rate as      'Conversion Rate',cast(convtimestamp as datetime) as 'Updated Time' 
 from Locations.dbo.Uni_Currency_Exchange_Rates 
 where fromCur = '" + FromCur.Text + "' and toCur = '" + ToCur.Text + "' order by ConvTimeStamp desc "
 Location2.SelectCommand = sSQL.ToString
 Dim command3 As New SqlCommand(sSQL, connection)

????????????????

End Sub
```

I need to generate html table code 
which create rows for each record

Like

```
<table>
<th>ID</th>
<th>From Currency</th>
<th>To Currency</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Update Time</th>
<tr>1</tr>..............................
<tr>2</tr>..............................
.............................
</Table>
```

to display the results like this.

**ID  | From Currency |  To Currency | Rate | Update Time**

1 | MVR | USD |15.42 | 3/25/14 12:00:00

1 | MVR | EUR |22.00 | 3/25/14 12:00:00

Is there a short way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

You could create a `Table` object and populate your rows and cells with loops.

Comment: Ya its Asp.net 4.5 (aspx page)

Comment: in which case what type of page are you using MVC? forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Kind of old school but I'm not aware of any easier way to do this.

Create a Table object

```
Dim myTable as Table
```

Create a DataReader - pseudo code here

```
Dim dr as DataReader = command.executeReader
while reader.Read()
TableRow r = new TableRow()
TableCell cell = new TableCell()
cell.Text = reader(0)
r.Cells.Add(cell)
myTable.Rows.Add(r)
next
```

`Table` exposes objects for header rows and header cells as well. This is probably the easiest way to do it. (You would repeat the cell creation and population for each column in your row, add the cells to the row, and then add the row to the table)

Unless you want to use XML, serialization, and XSLT I don't know of any other way to do this...

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was just started using vbnet

Comment: You can also drop the table on your page (using an <asp:Table id="myTable" runat="server") and refer to it that way. With the method I mentioned you'll need to add the control to the page.

Comment: You know what - you could also use a GridView, which would populate the table automatically. I totally forgot about that option since it sounded like you wanted to do something custom with it.

Comment: ya. you were right, that i am doing a custom coding with it. i didn't used grid view because i couldn't format the rows ans columns, the way i want using grid view, but in a table i can format like as html